# Find DOM in content panel asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

Please Help!
How i can find DOM element :

```
<asp:Content .....>
....
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat ="server" Text="Test"></asp:TextBox>
....
</asp:Content>
```

From PopUp window i will change atribute Text, But in JScode  like 
...

```
DOM = document.getelementByID("txt1")
```

is null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [client-side ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) of the Textbox:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("<%= txt1.ClientID %>");
```